# ACF Repeater loops and resets - where is the reset_rows() documentation?

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields, reset, wp-reset-postdata, get-row

I love ACF, its great for developers and it seems to have so much support. BUT... Why is reset_rows() not in the documentation? I created a function that can delete repeater rows at different times in the code. I was using the rows loop each time expecting it to start at index 0 (or 1 in acf's crazy way). But each loop started where the previous one left off.

This gave me grief for quite a while. I have only found **ONE** other topic with a small 3 word reply mentioning reset_rows(). ACF documentation has nothing that comes up when you searched reset_rows() or anything about reseting the row index. ITS NO WHERE!

So maybe this can save others from the grief. Here is how i use it successfully:

`reset_rows('field_name', $post_id);`

$post_id could be optional, havnt tried it..

Here is how i have placed it in my code

```
if( have_rows('related_trustees', $memberID) )
{
    reset_rows('related_trustees', $memberID); // Start from begining (protects against previous loops)
    echo 'Have rows';
    $rowNum = 0; // ACF Rows start at index of 1
    while( have_rows('related_trustees', $memberID) )
    {
        the_row();
        $rowNum ++;
        if(get_sub_field('trustee') == $userID)
        {
            $delrow = delete_row('related_trustees', $rowNum, $memberID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if theres a reason to this madness please.

Comment: I understand ACF is a third party plugin. But ACF's popularity in Wordpress should give it some leeway.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree.  I've been using ACF for years, and I don't do a WP project without it.  Your tip fixed a problem for me that seems to have been introduced in the most recent version of ACF, so thanks!

Comment: I take that back -- not a bug in ACF. Turns out I was having the problem because of another area where I was going through the same loop.  But reset_rows() allowed me to fix the issue, so thanks again!

Comment: Np! The good old power of stack exchange, let one of us trip so the rest can walk around the stump.

Comment: there should be a wordpress-plugins.stackexchange.com... so this would be ON-topic... sigh.

Comment: Ridiculous that this got closed - but the use of the row reset higher in the loop actually saved me on a project. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not in the documentation mainly because it's an internal function, they weren't expecting you to use or need it.

`have_rows()` checks to see whether there is a currently active loop- if not, it creates a global with your repeater rows; if so, it picks up where you left off- then it lets you know whether there are rows remaining to be looped through.  Your example is intriguing, seems to be a bit of a fringe scenario, but I can see how frustrating it would be.  After jumping out of the loop midstream, you aren't automatically returned to the beginning because the previous loop is still active and has rows remaining.

ACF doesn't have a true `rewind_posts()` equivalent, but you can either run the `reset_rows()` function or the function it's wrapping: `acf_remove_loop()` (also internal and undocumented, sorry!).  Whichever you use should probably be run right before your `break` though, so you don't end up with unexpected results from your `if ( have_rows() )` should you ever be removing the last row and following it up with another loop.

An unrelated but interesting tidbit is that you actually don't need the custom row counter, they provide `get_row_index()` for just this purpose.

Comment: Thank you Steven for the insight. It would be great if the documentation had this function. I am a control freak haha. That is good to know about the index function!